# Ruby Regex - Need to replace every occurrence of a character inside a regex match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my string:

`mystring = %Q{object1="this is, a testyay', asdkf'asfkd", object2="yo ho', ho"}`

I am going to split `mystring` on commas, therefore I want to (temporarily) sub out the commas that lie in between the escaped quotes.

So, I need to match escaped quote + some characters + one or more commas + escaped quote and then gsub the commas in the matched string.

The regex for gsub I came up with is `/(".*?),(.*?")/`, and I used it like so:
`newstring = mystring.gsub(/(".*?),(.*?")/ , "\\1|TEMPSUBSTITUTESTRING|\\2")`, but this only replaces the first comma it finds between the escaped quotes.

How can I make it replace all the commas?

Thanks.

Comment: `require 'csv'; CSV.parse(mystring)` and you don't need the troublesome regex.

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is an excellent place to tinker with your expression.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is one way to achieve the results you are wanting.

```
newstring = mystring.gsub(/".*?,.*?"/) {|s|  s.gsub( ",", "|TEMPSUBSTITUTESTRING|" ) }
```

It passes the matched string (the quoted part) to the code block which then replaces all of the occurrences of the comma.  The initial regex could probably be `/".*?"/`, but it would likely be less efficient since the code block would be invoked for each quoted string even if it did not have a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with all that, just split `mystring` on this regex:

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

The lookahead asserts that the comma is followed by an even number of quotes, meaning it's *not* inside a quoted value.