# Regex: how to replace a character inside a match pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a certain pattern

> XXX >>> [a, b, c]

inside a huge chunk of text and I want to replace all "," in the matched texts only with say ".", so I get

> XXX >>> [a. b. c]

**Is it possible to do it with Regex only (c# flavor) and if yes how?**

Updates:

I dont want to replace all comma with dots in the whole text!
It is similar to this question, but it is unfortunately not the same: [Ruby Regex - Need to replace every occurrence of a character inside a regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229790/ruby-regex-need-to-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-character-inside-a-regex-matc)
and I have no problem identifying the pattern which consists of

- prefix "XXX >>> ["
- target body where commas needs to be replaced, e.g. "a, b, c, d"
- suffix "]"

Solution:
`(?<=XXX >>> \[|\G)([^][,]*),(?=[^][]*\])`

The tricks are

- \G
- Matching group statement

Comment: Search for ',' and replace by '.' - no regex needed here... see https://regex101.com/r/iS0oT8/1

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to blindly replace all commas with periods...you just want to replace them when they are found inside this pattern, correct?

Comment: Yes Aaron you are 100% correct!

Comment: Any chance of embedded brackets `xxx>>>{a[a1,a2,a3],b,c]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```
(?<=XXX >>> \[|\G)([^][,]*),(?=[^][]*\])
```

And use `"$1."` for replacement.

- [RegEx Demo 1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3DXXX%20%3E%3E%3E%20%5C%5B%7C%5CG)(%5B%5E%5D%5B%2C%5D*)%2C(%3F%3D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5C%5D)&i=ab%2C%20xy%2C%20de%20XXX%20%3E%3E%3E%20%5Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%5D%20foo%2C%20bar%2C%20baz&r=%241.)
- [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/yC5gG2/1)

Comment: Living dangerous [^`]`[,] with this class.

Comment: It does work without escaping inside a character class but of course it can be escaped as `[^\]\[,]`

Comment: If not escaping the `]` literal, it can only exist as the first character, or the first one following the not `^`. Otherwise, its a class termination delimiter. Unless its Java or something, then its a delimiter.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Ok the matching group is where I had the trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two phases.  First, grab the part of the line containing the commas to be replaced:

```
(XXX\s>>>\s)(\[[^\]]*\])
```

This captures two groups: the `XXX >>>` part, and the `[a, b, c]` part.  Then, do a simple replace of comma->period on the second part.  Finally, concatenate the two parts back together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aaron, it is of course a possibility, however I want to have a generic solution with Regex.